Issue with Python script updating MySQL table rows to set a column to NULL
I'm encountering an issue with a Python script that updates rows in a MySQL database table. The script is intended to set the contact_id column to NULL for all rows where contact_id is currently set to 1 in the aos_products table. However, when I run the script, it doesn't seem to update the rows as expected. Instead, it encounters an error message "Error: Unread result found".
Here's the relevant portion of the Python script:
if result == 0:
    query = "UPDATE aos_products SET contact_id=NULL WHERE contact_id=1"
    cursor.execute(query)

    # Log date and actions performed
    with open("ADILog.txt", "a") as f:
      f.write(f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')} Actions Performed: {action_count} Actions Left: {result - action_count} Finished Uploading\n")

    print("All Results Updated and Reset to process on next run")
    exit()

I cant get it to work and it seems to fail with 'cursor.execute(query)' part, any idea on my solution would be greatly appreciated.

bypass python: run your query with the mysql repl: does that work? (and of course: have you already searched for this error?)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The problem is that you tried to reuse the cursor object, but it still had results remaining from its previous query.
Either fetch all of the results from the prior query before using the cursor for a new query, or else use a fresh cursor.
